# Can I immigrate to the USA while working remotely for an Australia-based company?

Tags: usa, australia

I currently work remotely for an Australian company and live in Australia. In the future I would like to permanently immigrate to the USA to live with my girlfriend, who is a U.S. citizen. My employer has approved for me to continue working remotely for the Australian company from the US.

I'm not sure if I qualify for an employment or business based visa because I won't be employed by a US company. If possible, I would like to avoid consecutive traveller's visas that require me to return to Australia periodically when they expire.

I am open to applying for a K-1 fiancee visa and marrying my girlfriend within 90 days of arriving in the USA, but I'd like to know what other options there are for me.

Comment: Well you can only get a work visa from a USA company petitioning you to work for them, or an internal transfer from a company in Australia to their offices in USA if they have them. So your only real option is K1 or if you get married before IR1 or CR1. K1 is the better route.

Comment: "I would like to avoid consecutive traveller's visas that require me to return to Australia periodically when they expire": that isn't an option in any event since such a plan would violate the terms of the visitor visa on at least two counts, namely that work is not permitted on a visitor visa and that you wouldn't be *visiting* the US but living there.

Comment: As an Australian (assuming you *are* an Australian citizen), one of your best options is the [E-3 visa](http://www.ustraveldocs.com/au/au-niv-typee3.asp), but this requires an employment offer for a "specialty occupation" (requiring a Bachelor's or higher degree) from a sponsoring employer in the US.